# show next 365 days from current day using Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to create a Date picker in a scrollable list. There, I need to show next 365 days from current date using simple Javascript (please no jQuery). Suppose, today is Oct 11. So, in a scrollable list, it will show Oct 11 to Nov 11 to Dec 11 to Jan 11 to continuous. Please check my code below. It will show the current today date. I need a loop which will show upto next 365 days.

```js
function Ctrl($scope){   
   $scope.dates = [];
   for (i=1; i<=365; i++){
     $scope.dates.push(new Date());
   }
}
```

```html
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="date in dates">{{date | date:'MMM-dd'}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very simple array to create...what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried this:-  for (i=1; i<=365; i++){
    $scope.date = new Date();
    }

Comment: that will over write the value each iteration... create array instead

Comment: Also, instead of 10, I want to print Oct. Is there any to print month name instead of month sequence number?

Comment: See date filter docs for formats

Comment: [date filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)
    `'MMMM': Month in year (January-December)` or `'MMM': Month in year (Jan-Dec)`

Comment: Can someone help me, where should I use array, any hints? I am still trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest update has gotten you pretty close to what you want to achieve.  However, you are currently creating an array with 365 `Date` objects all with the current Date and Time.  You will need to use the [`setDate()` method](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) to add days to your date, to create a consecutive array.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.dates = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= 364; i++) {
    var d = new Date();
    $scope.dates.push(d.setDate(d.getDate() + i));
  }
}
```

Based on your comment, I changed the for loop to start from 0 through 364, to start from today (`Date() + 0`).  Note that this is ALWAYS going to start from the current date that the script is run on; i.e. if you run the script on Oct. 12, it will start then, if you run the script on Oct. 20, it will start from there.

Comment: It is starting from Oct 13. But today is Oct 12. I need to show current date too.

Comment: then start from `i=0` instead of `1`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Also can we add any validation to check the 365 or 366?

Comment: not sure what you mean, add validation to check what exactly?

Comment: Year is leap year or not. In leap year, it's 366 days. I am calculating one year.

Comment: JavaScript dates should take this into account automatically, since they are based on the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.  If you need to count an extra day if it's a leap year, you should maybe consider using a date library like moment.js, instead of trying to calculate all the possibilities yourself.